# Cascading grid layout library

Tags: php, jquery, css

There is pretty library for grid layout - Masonry ([Cascading grid layout library](http://masonry.desandro.com/))
And there is one website which use this - [thereason.us](http://thereason.us/)

I want to know how tiles are made different sizes? I mean that I know that there are different styles - portrait cropped, portrait real, large, medium, landscape, large_landscape, etc., but how they are assigned to be so amazing - manual or there is some algorithm? I haven't seen any sequence in layout to be automatic, so can anybody tell me how I can assign different styles automatically to be the same?

Comment: i think how to size is in the [options] page...

Comment: you don't understand ) i know about options on http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html and there is note about css styling, but my question is how implement such grid layout - manual or automatic. i can see that these - thereason.us - layout is not random, but how - i don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Masonry is a 1d bin-packing solver. It tries to minimize gaps in the wall and it's an optimization problem. Note that the wall is build not with rows. It uses a vertical grid. With packery you can also control the row size so maybe it can solve a 2d bin-packing problem. You can also try a dynamic programming solution to solve a bin-packing problem.